# Jenkins is sending emails before the build finishes

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins which sends email before completing the whole build. The job is configured to build the code and also to run a SonarQube scan, but Jenkins sends email when it is finished with building the code, but not after the SonarQube scan.

How can I set the email after the SonarQube scan?

Answer (score 0):

A SonarQube scan is done as a post build action as I recall. As is email sending. Which do you have first in your configuration? Can you drag down the email?

If that's not it, can you  share the configuration of your job? One way to do that is to got to the job page and had config.xml to the URL. This gives you the XML version of your configuration that you can post here.